# gomodule/redigo how can I push multiple keys to redis

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I am trying to rpush multiple elements to a redis key. Currently using a redis pool connection using https://github.com/gomodule/redigo.

If I try to put an array into rpush , a string with the array concatenated is pushed. How can I push individual elements instead

```
conn := Pool.Get() // A redigo redis pool 
arr := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
conn.Do("RPUSH","TEST","x","y") // This works
conn.Do("RPUSH", "TEST", arr) //This does not work
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the library but from what I saw on their documentation, I guess that this should work:

```
conn.Do("RPUSH", arr...)
```

`...` is a parameter operator that unpacks the elements of your slice and passes as them separate arguments to a variadic function, which would be the same as this:

```
arr := []string{"TEST", "a", "b", "c", "d"}

conn.Do("RPUSH", "TEST", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
```

More information can be found on variadic function in go [in this very complete article](https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-variadic-funcs-how-to-patterns-369408f19085)

Comment: args := []interface{"TEST"} Gives me an error

unexpected literal "TEST", expecting method or interface name

Comment: @ThunderCat yeah wasn't sure about that. In the end then, he just needs to add his `TEST` value to the `arr` string as well. Editing the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Build a slice of the arguments and call the variadic function with those arguments:

```
 args := []interface{"TEST")
 for _, v := range arr {
   args = append(args, v)
 }
 conn.Do("RPUSH", args...)
```

The [Args](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Args) helper does the same thing with a single line of application code:

```
 conn.Do("RPUSH", edis.Args{}.Add("TEST").AddFlat(arr)...)
```